# How to register a pipe inside a component rather that a module in angular?

Tags: angular

How can I register a pipe inside a component rather than a module in angular?

Currently we are registering a pipe inside a module in which the component is also registered.

How can we instead register it inside the component?

Since this pipe is not used anywhere else, it can be localized to the component itself.

Currently I'm providing it inside the component. But that give back error that the pipe is not found.

```
@Component({
...,
providers:[FilterPipe],
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#the-pipetransform-interface) you will have to:

> You must include your pipe in the declarations array of the AppModule.
>
> If you choose to inject your pipe into a class, you must provide it in
> the providers array of your NgModule.

That means, you will have to **at least** add the pipe to the components module within the `declarations` array. It will then be accessible by all the components within that module. If you also want to inject the pipe into one of your components, you will additionally have to add it to the `providers` array of the components module.

So, if you want to use the pipe inside your `foo.component.ts`, you will have to additionally add it to the constructor and let the DI do the heavy lifting like so:

```
@Component()
export class FooComponent {
  constructor(
    private readonly _filterPipe: FilterPipe,
  )
}
```

If you *just* want to use the pipe inside `foo.component.html`, then it is enough to have it defined inside the components module `declaration` array.

```
// your.module.ts
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {YourPipe} from '..';
import {FooComponent} from '..';

// The module where your FooComponent is declared.
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // Your imports
  ],
  providers: [
    // Your pipe comes here, **if** you want to use it inside `foo.component.ts`
    YourPipe,
    // ...
  ],
  declarations: [
    FooComponent,
    YourPipe, // Declare the pipe here to use it inside `foo.component.html`
    // ...
  ],
})
export class YourModule {
}
```

Comment: How Can I do that? Can you show me a sample code? How to create module declaration array?

Comment: Added an example module definition.

Comment: This is something I know.

Comment: Sooo... did it work or did you face other problems?